# emguCV- how to position an Image over another image

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I want to add an image over another image in emguCV at specific position. Addweighted() don't allow positioning. Is there any way i can position the image.

for example i have an image1 of 640x480 and i want to add a drop of water 10x30 on image1 at position 60x200. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same thing as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991523/opencv-draw-an-image-over-another-image) with EmguCV function. In fact, just select a ROI and copy your second image to this ROI. Then, cancel the ROI.

Hope it helps!